# reading "prettified" JSON back into python

Tags: python, json, string

Suppose I have a dict in python, like so:

```
original = {
    "x": 1.0,
    "y": "Floyd",
    "z": "Floyd\'s friend Larry",
}
```

The dict gets JSON encoded and then written to an .ipynb file that prettifies it for human consumption when viewed in a browser.  I want to read in the .ipynb file and recover the original dict.

The .ipynb file, when viewed in the browser, renders as so:

```
renders_as = {
    'x': 1.0,
    'y': 'Floyd',
    'z': "Floyd\'s friend Larry",
}
```

This is manually copy-and-paste-able as a python dict equivalent to the original.

However, when I read in the .ipynb file using python I instead get the following string:

```
'{\'x\': 1.0, \'y\': \'Floyd\', \'z\': \\"Floyd\'s friend Larry\\"}'
```

This is not proper JSON, so I can't `json.loads`, and it is not a string literal that can be assigned using something like `ast.load_literal` because the double back-slashes parse as line continuations.

What is the best way for me to take this string and produce the original input, while protecting myself from the usual string processing issues such as dealing with potentially nested quotes?

Comment: How do you write the json-encoded dict to the .ipynb file? Could you share a [MRE]?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unicode-escape` to process the escaped string first:

```
import ast

value = '{\'x\': 1.0, \'y\': \'Floyd\', \'z\': \\"Floyd\'s friend Larry\\"}'
value = value.encode("utf-8")
value = value.decode("unicode-escape")
value = ast.literal_eval(value)

# value = {'x': 1.0, 'y': 'Floyd', 'z': "Floyd's friend Larry"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was to read the .ipynb file back into memory as JSON.    (I had been reading line by line as ordinary strings).  By reading the file as JSON, the call to `json.load()` handled the nested quotes for me, and left the object as a proper dict that I could read in using `ast.literal_eval`.